# How to plot a large dataset with Flutter

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, plot

I have a file with a large dataset, that I'd like to plot. The dataset itself is a series of `N` integers stored in a binary file, and each time point is relative to `S` different signals (rain precipitation in various locations).

So my dataset is basically, if I have 3 locations, as

```
S0:0 S1:0 S2:0 S0:1 S1:1 S2:1 S0:2   ... S0:t S1:t S2:t
|            | |            | |          |            |
+------------+ +------------+ +--        +------------+
    time 0        time 1             ...     time t
```

The number of time points per sensor can vary, but an average would be 1M-2M. The number of sensors is usually less than 40, but let's say 100 to be safe.

The approach I am using right now is to load the file, construct the `N` different `List`s, and then using `SfCartesianChart` from SyncFusion.

**This is immensely slow**.

On a computer it hangs the application, and I didn't even try to start the app on a smartphone.

I thought it was a file-related problem, so I have substituted with one single sine wave function, and just one signal right now (not multiple plots):

```
class TestData
{
  double t; // time
  double V; // vertical displacement

  TestData(this.t, this.V);
}

...

@override
  void initState() {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nsamples; i++) {
      // THIS IS FOR TEST ONLY: sine at .5 Hz
      points.add(TestData(i * time, sin(2.0 * pi * (0.5) * i * time)));
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppStatus>(
      builder: (context, appStatus, child) {
        return ScaffoldPage.scrollable(
          children: [
            FilledButton(child: Text("${widget.fileName} ${appStatus.count}"), onPressed: (){ debugPrint('pressed ${widget.fileName}'); }),
            SfCartesianChart(
              primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(visibleMaximum: 25),
              series: <LineSeries<TestData, num>>[
                LineSeries<TestData, num>(
                  animationDuration: 2500,
                  // Binding list data to the chart.
                  dataSource: points,
                  xValueMapper: (TestData rain, _) => rain.t,
                  yValueMapper: (TestData rain, _) => rain.V,
                ),
              ]
            )
          ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with acceptable performances?

Of course users would like to pan/zoom and scroll through the data, and I am really unsure about what I am doing right now, given my performances (and yes, the hang it's in release mode, in debug mode is obviously even slower).

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: If it's a performance issue when processing the data, you could look into `isolate` to offload intense computations to a new "thread". Side question, you said "I didn't even try to start the app on a smartphone", and "yes, the hang it's in release mode", did you run release mode on a simulator?

Comment: @Riwen I have added more details and some code. I removed the file loading and parsing, and I am just using one signal, a sine wave, and just 100K samples. It is utterly slow. If I try to pan, the app hangs.

Comment: @user1032613 I'll read about `isolate` right away. For your question, no, I first run as a desktop app, and being that slow, I didn't even dare to run in the simulator.

Comment: @senseiwa Have you ever figured it out or did you end up writing something custom?

Comment: @simonescu unfortunately, speed isn't Flutter's strongest suit, I ended up switching to C++ with Qt. This is after I've also contacted SyncFusion support for their plotting library, they said it's impossible with these sizes.